# Robot FrameWork:: How to Count Arguments?

Tags: python, robotframework

Is there any way to dynamically Count how many Arguments has been passed to a keyword AND is there a way to print arguments like Log ${Argument1}, ${Argument2}?. for E.g.  There are some 10 check boxes to select. but in TC QA selects only few items which he/she sends as argument to a keyword. So, We want to capture all the list of arguments to create a List and iterate through them to select the right check boxes

```
Add Arguments to List
    [Arguments]   arg1  arg2  arg3  arg4  arg5 
    ${NoOf_Arguments}  =   #TODO: no idea how to count no of arguments
    @{List_To_Create}=  Create List
    : For ${item}  IN RANGE ${NoOf_Arguments}
    \   append to list  ${List_To_Create} ${item}
    [Return]  ${List_To_Create}
```

Comment: Pass all arguments as a list `[Arguments]    @{args}` and then handle them as list items. You can count them, log the list etc.

Comment: If you hard-code five arguments, you must pass five arguments or robot will throw an error. Are you asking how to support a variable number of arguments?

Comment: @BryanOakley, In my e.g. its 5 .. but in real time it can be more then 1. i.e. like n variables .. so i wanted to know A. how find how many arguments passed. B. how to bring them all into List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robot supports a variable number of arguments by having the last item in `[Arguments]` be a list variable.

For example:

```
*** Keywords ***
A keyword
    [Arguments]  @{args}
    ${count}=  get length  ${args}
    log  you passed in ${count} arguments
    :FOR  ${arg}  IN  @{args}
    \  log  argument: ${arg}
    [return]  ${count}    

*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  A keyword  arg1  arg2  arg3
    should be equal as numbers  ${result}  3

    ${result}=  A keyword  arg1  arg2  arg3  arg4  arg5
    should be equal as numbers  ${result}  5
```

Comment: Pl tell me if this keyword is right!! (we dont have access to execute thats the reason) Select Required Tenant Groups
    [Documentation]  Clicks on Checkbox button to select the given value
    [Arguments]   @{Tenant_Groups_To_Select}
    :For ${item}  IN RANGE  @{Tenant_Groups_To_Select}
    \  Selenium2Library.Select Checkbox  //*[@id="ctl00_PageBody_TenantsList"]/tbody/tr/td/label[normalize-space(text())='${item}']/preceding-sibling::input

Comment: @bbk: it doesn't look right to me. `:FOR ... IN RANGE` requires a number as an argument, and you're providing a list of arguments. You want `IN`, not `IN RANGE`.